# process substitution not working in ksh on AIX

Tags: ksh

The following loop runs perfectly in `bash` on Linux and Solaris but fails on AIX with default `ksh`:

```
while read -r line; do
    var1=$(...)
    var2=$(...)
    echo "$var1  $var2"
done < <(lsvgfs `lsvg | grep -v rootvg`)
```

with the following message:

> 0403-057 Syntax error at line 11 : `<' is not expected.

Comment: `< <(lsvgfs \`lsvg | grep -v rootvg\`)` is process substitution and is BASH specific, not supported in ksh.

Comment: I think it's more likely it's the modern `<()` construction that's not working, rather than the redirect.  Well, I think of it as modern, but I can't say when it was added.  (See [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch07_03.htm): "Process substitution is only available on Unix systems that support the /dev/fd/N special files for named access to already open file descriptors."

Comment: Always include your `ksh` version please (I guess you're running `ksh88`) as this works just fine in `ksh93`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
lsvgfs `lsvg | grep -v rootvg` | while read -r line; do
           var1=$(...)
           var2=$(...)
           echo "$var1  $var2"
done
```

Comment: This will work as long as `var1` and `var2` are not needed after the loop ends.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: Yes, that is a disadvantage because every pipe member is executed in its own shell.

Comment: Correct. Just wanted to make sure it was pointed out. A temporary file is the other alternative that will allow the main shell variable visibility (the only other alternative at all that I'm aware of actually).

Comment: I wouldn't call it the _only_ other alternative; one can always resort to named pipes.

Comment: In ksh you still have the vars after the loop.